# SVG don't add to webpack project on React

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, config

I have a problem with uploading SVG icons in React. Only .png files upload correctly. When I run npm run dev, I get an error in console:
GET http://localhost:8080/[object%20Module] net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

That's how I use svg in the .scss file,the path to the file is correct for sure:
background-image: url('./img/actions.svg');

My config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { outputConfig, copyPluginPatterns, entryConfig, devServer } = require("./env.config");

module.exports = (env, options) => 
{
    return {
        mode: options.mode,
        entry: entryConfig,
        devServer,
        target: "web",
        module: {
            rules: [
       
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        "style-loader",
                        "css-loader",
                        {
                            loader: "postcss-loader",
                            options: {
                                postcssOptions: {
                                    plugins: [
                                        ["postcss-preset-env"],
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        "sass-loader"
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/i,
                    type: "javascript/auto",
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        publicPath: "../",
                        name: "[path][name].[ext]",
                        context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets"),
                        emitFile: false,
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/,
                    type: "javascript/auto",
                    exclude: /images/,
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        publicPath: "../",
                        context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets"),
                        name: "[path][name].[ext]",
                        emitFile: false,
                    },
                },
            ],
        }        
    };
};
```

Comment: What's the version of webpack are you using?

Comment: version webpack 9.5.0

Comment: The latest webpack version is `5.88.2`

Comment: Sorry, that was npm.  "webpack": "^5.73.0". Actually, if I add svg to <img> it works correctly, but not in background-image